# Renombrar fichero python

Tags: python

¿Alguien sabe cómo renombrar un fichero con Python?

Lo que hago es que finalice la funcion leer y luego llamo la otra función para que lo renombre. No hay manera de hacer las dos cosas al mismo tiempo, me dice que otro proceso esté utilizando el archivo.

Este es mi código:

```
import csv

def leer():
m1=open("archivo1.csv","rb")
m1_csv=csv.reader(m1)
var = ""


for i,x in enumerate(m1_csv):


    lista0 = x[0:1]
    lista1 = x[1:2]
    header = str1 = ''.join(lista0)
    header1 = header[9:13]
    str1 = ''.join(lista1)
    str1 = str1[1:]
    str2 = str1[0:32]


    listas = []
    listas.append("The next header ")
    listas.append(header1)
    listas.append("")
    if(header1=="goin"):
        listas.remove("")
        listas.remove("goin")
        listas.append("error")  
        listas.append(" the hash is outdate: "+str2)        
    elif(header1=="omin"):
        listas.remove("")
        listas.remove("omin")
        listas.append("error")  
        listas.append(" the hash is outdate: "+str2)            
    elif( str2 == "074e3e3e82db7610dbeafd95c22d20a2"):
        listas.remove("")
        listas.append(" is using for speaking")
        listas.append(" example bla bla bla the packet")
        listas.append(" Incident: you can get powers")



    listo=["OUTGOING HEADERS"]
    listos=["INCOMING HEADERS"]

    m2_c=csv.writer(open("archivo2.csv","a"),lineterminator='\n')
    if(i==0):
        m2_c.writerow(listo)
    if(i==468):
        m2_c.writerow(listos)
    m2_c.writerow(listas)




m1.close()
```

Probe a hacerlo con el método `os` pero me da un error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "prueba1.py", line 64, in <module>
    leer()
  File "prueba1.py", line 54, in leer
    os.remove("archivo1.csv")
WindowsError: [Error 32] Le processus ne peut pas accÚde
ier est utilisÚ par un autre processus: 'archivo1.csv'
```

Comment: lo que hago es que finalice la funcion leer y luego llamo la otra funcion para que lo renombre no hay manera de hacer las dos cosas al mismo tiempo me dice otro proceso esta utilizando el archivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio tendría que funcionar, aunque yo prefiero usar:

```
with open(file) as csv_data:
     data = csv.reader(csv_data, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
     # Process data
```

Por otro lado, para renombrar un archivo lo que hago es:

```
import os
os.rename(old_filename_with_path, new_filename_with_path)
```

Comment: +1 por el `with open()`, además puedes abrir en una línea múltiples archivos : `with open('a') as a, open('b') as b, ..., open('n') as n :`

Answer (score 0):

Comment sa va, el problema es lo que indica el mensaje de error:

> WindowsError: [Error 32] Le processus ne peut pas accÚde ier est
>   utilisÚ par un autre processus: 'archivo1.csv'

Recuerda que si abres el archivo,

```
m1=open("archivo1.csv","rb")
```

tienes que cerrarlo,

```
m1.close()
```

ya que si vuelves a tratar de abrirlo, provocará el error:

> [Error 32] being used by another process

, que indica que otro proceso esta utilizando el archivo.

**Primero soluciona este detalle ya que veo no únicamente estas renombrando el archivo, en realidad estas abriendo un archivo y su contenido para posteriormente agregar este y más contenido al archivo2.csv.**